# left div percentage width, right fills remaining space

Tags: html, css

I have a left div floating left with a percentage width, and a right div floating left that I would like to take up the remaining space, here is a [fiddle]: https://jsfiddle.net/gfhfku8k/. Thanks, for any help in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">

  </div>
  <div class="right">

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.left {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.right {
  height: 100%;
  /* width: 30px; */
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Comment: Without looking at anything - have you tried 70% width on a right div? Of course you would need to set box-sizing: border-box

Comment: Do you want the .right div to remaining full width?

Comment: Yes, I would like the right div to take up the remaining space, but the left div's width will change width. 30% is just an example, sorry should of specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming putting `width: 70%` on the right column isn't what you're looking for, this kind of layout is most easily accomplished with `flex`. Here's how it works:

Note that I removed the `float` property on the columns, and added `box-sizing: border-box` to all elements (`*`) for it to work properly (though it's not needed for this demo).

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  /* flex */
  display: flex;
}
.left,
.right {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.left {
  background: pink;
  width: 30%;
}
.right {
  background: blue;
  /* flex */
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="left">
  </div>

  <div class="right">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I haven't used flex before, but I'll definitely have to start learning about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
.right {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Just remove float:left from .right class.